# How to limit width of chosen web pages in firefox

Tags: firefox

I have wide monitor and texts on many pages have just too wide lines. Is there any add on or way how to limit width of these pages. So I can read them comfortably?

Comment: Could you just reduce the width of your browser window?

Comment: I could, but I hope there is better solution. I would like to set which pages should be less wide and which not.

Comment: Hold CTRL+mouse wheel scroll down.

Comment: Try it on Wikipedia, it don't work. And I just want shorter lines, not smaller text size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Firefox extension which does exactly what you want: Dr. Body Narrow (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dr-body-narrow/)

Comment: thanks, that's it. It would be great if it could remember which pages I want to shrink, but this is good too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try GreaseMonkey - Every webpage has a `<BODY>` tag - so you could set a max-width of the body tag thus preventing website widths from being too wide!

However, if you alter the normal behaviour in this way, there could be other implications, such as the website doesn't layout as it should, or even doesn't function as it should. Trial and error!!

Comment: Sadly, that approach isn't very compatible. If a webpage goes full-width with their text (e.g. some HTML manuals), setting <body>'s max-width to 60em works well. If the website uses the horizontal space for ads, doing so might result in the text column having a line break after every single character.